# check if array values in 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a simple question in C language, so, I want to check if array values exists in the second array(2d array), no matter the order of the values(random order)

for example:

I want to check the values in `arr[3]={1,2,3}` if all of them exist in `mat[3][3]={{1,5,3},{4,5,6},{4,2,5}};`

in this case, the values exists so the program will `print ("OK");`

note: I don't want to count the same value twice

Comment: for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
  for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
  {
   if (mat[i][j] == arr[i])
    count++;
  }
 }

Comment: Please post your code *in the question*.

Comment: Posting OP's comment buried inside an answer: *"I want to check if 1 and 2 and 3 together exists minimum 1 time in random order in the 2D array "*

Comment: the edits int the original post completely changed the meaning of the question, making all the existing answers and most of the comments irrelevant.  i suggest to remove this question completely.

Comment: It is not changing in the meaning it's more clear now, the commenters said that it was not understandable so I edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, thank's for all, I really appreciate your answers

```
#define n 3
    int *p = &vec[0];
int count1 = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (*p <= vec[2])
        {
            if (*p == mat[i][j])
            {
                p++;
                count1++;
                i=0;
                j=0;
            }
        }
    }
}

if(count1 == 3) printf("ok");
```

Comment: 1) `i=0; j=0;` : This will not make the next search the top search. 2) `*p <= 3` might occurs out bounds access. (Also, the end of the array to be searched should not be a fixed number.)

Comment: My friend, first of all I tried the code and it is working, and second i made the i=0 and j=0 to search the second value again just like we did with the first value

Comment: This will not work as expected. See [DEMO](http://ideone.com/AJRJzL)

Comment: _i made the i=0 and j=0 to search the second value again just like we did with the first value_  Note that **it is incremented at the end of for-loop**.

Comment: Look, the important thing in the whole code is the value of the count, try it again and I am sure you will agree with me

Comment: Again, See link of DEMO in previous comment.

Comment: Had you compiled the code?

Comment: See DEMO.......

Comment: Also another case `{{3, 2, 1},{4, 5, 6},{7, 8, 9}}` [DEMO2](http://ideone.com/q08VZa) Try compile and run it.

Comment: really this is your solution ? @YousufHardan

Comment: @unreleased yes why?

Comment: The execution result of your code is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

here is an example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[3] = {1,2,3};
    int b[3][3] = {{1,5,3},{4,5,6},{4,2,5}};
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (a[j] != b[i][j]) break;
            if ( j == 2) {
                printf("exists in row %d\n", i);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("does not exists\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's not helpful first of all why break when you did not check all the values and why j == 2?

Comment: @YousufHardan `break` is there because equality is violated and there is no reason to check for other elements. `j == 2` because the array was declared as a 3-element array, so `2` is the last index. If we did no break before, the comparison on all elements passed.  It checks `b`  against `a` row by row. it does not do any cross-products. So, why it is not helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through the top-level array. For each array inside it, iterate through *that* and compare each element to the corresponding element in the array you're searching for. If they're all equal, return true. If you get to the end of the outer for loop, return false.

EDIT:

Upon clarification, okay. How about making an array, called 'result', equal in size to the array you're searching for? Initialize each value in the result array to 0, then iterate through every element in the two-dimensional array. If the element matches one of the elements in your search term, set the corresponding value in the result array to 1. At the end, check your result array. If every value in it is equal to 1, then return true. Otherwise, return false.

Comment: "If they're all equal" - but for the example values which should produce "OK", the 1-D array does not occur.

Comment: Right, for the example he gave, you'd return false.

Comment: So this can't be a solution.

Comment: @WeatherVane The question formulation is rather vague...

Comment: To me, the question asks if every value in the 1D array occurs somewhere in the 2D array.

Comment: My assumption was that the example had a typo in it (5 is directly above 2 on the numeric keypad, and {1,5,3} is immediately followed by {4,5,6}). Given the vagueness of the original question, it's not implausible. However, it's possible that you're correct. The OP really should edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @WeatherVane It sounds like this, yes. But I am not sure it is what the OP actually need.

Comment: Oh I see, so `arr[3]={1,2,3}` was meant to be `arr[3]={1,5,3}`.

Comment: It's my guess. Only the OP can tell us for sure.

Comment: no the order of values is not important here, I want to find the values in random order

Comment: Could you please clarify more? If you are searching for {1,2,3} does that mean you will only accept "1" that is in the first position of the second-level arrays, or would {0,1,2} match the "1" here?

Comment: I want to check if 1 and 2 and 3 together exists minimum 1 time in random order in the 2D array

Comment: Edited answer to reflect what I think you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

for tables only - continuous data in memory required

returns 0 if any not found, 1 if all found

```
int FindVectorInMatrix(int *haystack, int rows, int columns, int *needle, int length) // as described by OP order does not matter
{
    int *tmp;
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        tmp = haystack;
        if (result < i) 
        {
           result = 0;
           break;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < rows * columns; j++)
        {
            if (*tmp++ == *needle) 
            {
                result++;
                break;
            }
        }
        needle++;
    }
    return !!result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Its easy just iterate through the array where you looking for the desired value and check if exits then break. Check this:

```
for(int a=0; a<3; a++)
{
    int cnt=0;
    for(int b=0;b<3; b++)
    {
        if(mat[a][b]==arr[b])cnt++;
        if(cnt==3){cout<<"ok"; return 0;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Its `c` not `c++`.

Comment: I just gave him the hint. Hope OP would understand.

Comment: Its still not completely valid. Prints `okokNotFound` EDIT: I added `NotFound` print behind loops.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the issue. Hope last edit is ok.